# How to upload file to the server?

Tags: firefox-addon

My Firefox addon [downloaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files) the file and saved that at temp folder. In result I have [nsIFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFile) instance.

How can I upload that file to another server? If I use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest), I don't understand how to pass that `nsIFile` to `FormData`.

Or, probably I shouldn't just download the file and save that in the temp folder - since the only usage of this file is to be uploaded to another server. Probably, I should keep the file (file size ~20Kb) in the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are POSTing the data to the server as application/x-www-form-urlencoded then you should base64 encode it using btoa() and include it as one of the POST parameters in the request body (i.e. the string passed to XMLHttpRequest.send()):

```
postbody = "body=" + btoa(fileContents);
xhr.send(postbody);
```

I agree that if you are just downloading the file and uploading it right away, you might as well keep it in memory since you're presumably going to load it into memory anyway in order to base64 encode the contents.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. Could you please clarify (1) how I can get fileContents having nsIFile, (2) how to download file to the memory and then upload that?

Comment: Re (1): should I read the file (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Reading_a_Binary_File)?

Comment: Well if you're reading the file into memory then you should need an nsIFile at all. You can just download it using XMLHttpRequest and use responseText, uploading it in the way I described in the answer. If you do have an nsIFile then yes, that snippet describes how to read from it.